# Modify list item based on key:value match python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say we have the following list:

```
my_list = [{'id': '1', 'status':'new'},
           {'id': '2', 'status':'closed'},
           {'id': '3', 'status':'new'}]
```

Is there a way to change the `'status'` of the dict with `'id':'1'`?

This way the list will result in:

```
my_list = [{'id': '1', 'status':'changed'},  # <---
           {'id': '2', 'status':'closed'},
           {'id': '3', 'status':'new'}]
```

I see that one approach could be something like:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i]['id'] == 'desired_id':
        my_list[i]['status'] = 'desired_status'
        break
```

Is this the only option or is there a "nicer" approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have an option to change your data's structure (a dict of dicts for example instead of list of dicts), then no - since it's a list, you'll have to loop over it to find the dict with the matching `id`. So, if you're confined to using a list, the only thing to change is to loop on items instead of indices:

```py
for d in my_list:
    if d['id'] == 'desired_id':
        d['status'] = 'desired_status'
        break
else:
    print("There is no ID matching the desired search")
```

***But***, if you can change your data to be, for example:

```py
my_dict = {'1': {'status': 'new'},
           '2': {'status': 'closed'},
           '3': {'status': 'new'}}
```

...then there is no need for loops at all (that is assuming that `id`s can't repeat):

```py
try:
    my_dict['desired_id']['status'] = 'desired_status'
except KeyError:
    print("There is no ID matching the desired search")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this a list of dict. looping through it would be the way that strikes my mind :

```
my_list = [{'id': '1', 'status':'new'},{'id': '2', 'status':'closed'},{'id': '3', 'status':'new'}]
  for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
        if j['id'] == '1':        
         my_list[i]['status']='changed'            
  print(my_list)
```